# How to include a default parameter in a class in Python?

Tags: python, class, default-value

I would like to create a default value in this python class. But when I try and do it I get an error that says, "self is not defined"

I know the answer is something simple, yet it eludes me at the moment. Anyone know why I cannot add a default parameter here?

Thanks in advance for your replies!

```
class Sort(object):
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst

    def halve(self, l = self.lst):### this line <--------------
        n1 = l[:len(l) / 2]
        n2 = l[len(l) /2:]
        return (n1,n2)
```

Comment: Parameters cannot be used from within the parameter list they are defined in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you need to designate a `None` default and check inside the method whether it's been passed in

```
class Sort(object):
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst

    def halve(self, l=None):
        if l is None: l = self.lst
        n1 = l[:len(l) / 2]
        n2 = l[len(l) /2:]
        return (n1,n2)
```

The parameters to a function are established when the function is created, not when it's called, so `self.lst` doesn't yet exist.

Also, see the ["Principle of Least Astonishment"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: Doesn't the creation of the class (and thus self.lst) come before the creation of the method? That's what i'm unclear on.

Comment: The creation of the *class* comes first, but the creation of the *instance* (and by extension, self), does not

Comment: put another, simpler way, `__init__` has not yet run when `halve` gets defined

Comment: But actually, no, it doesn't. First the functions are created, and then the type (class) is created from them.

Answer (score 3):

A better way to go about this, perhaps, would be:

```
def halve(self,l=None):
    if l is None:
        l = self.lst
    # code
```

As an aside: please don't name variables `l` el or `O` oh or `I` eye. They look like 1s and 0s in certain fonts and make things more difficult for everyone. If you want to signify that it's a generic list, use `lst` just as you have for your class variable! Better, name it by what it signifies: is this a list of grades? `grade_list`. Is it a list of numbers? `numbers`. Even if it's just `input_list` it's at least more readable than `lst` and FAR more readable than `l`

Comment: it's kinda funny but it was originally lst. I thought it might confuse people since it's already used in the constructor (is the __init__ method considered a constructor?)

Comment: (yes the `__init__` method is called the constructor)

Answer (score 1):

Since it is one of the method's parameters, `self` will only be defined *inside* `Sort.halve`, not on the line that declares it.  This means that you cannot access `self.lst` until you are inside the method.

As a workaround, you can do something like this:

```
def halve(self, l=None):
    if l is None:
        l = self.lst
    n1 = l[:len(l) / 2]
    n2 = l[len(l) /2:]
    return (n1,n2)
```

The above code assigns the `l` parameter of `Sort.halve` a default value of `None`.  When the method is invoked, it will use the if-statement to see if the caller supplied an argument for it or not.  If so, it will keep `l` equal to that. Otherwise, it will assign `l` to `self.lst`.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it does not seem useful for your purpose, you can avoid using `None` as a default placeholder, as you can use `*args` to collect all arguments in one list:

```
def halve(self, *args):
    if not args: # if arg is an empty list / no arguments given
        lst = self.lst
    else:
        lst = args[0]
    # code
```

or in one line:

```
def halve(self, *args):
    lst = self.lst if not args else args[0]
    # code
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have shown how you can deal with your problem, but I would like to clear up exactly why your code isn't working.

Imagine you have the code:

```
def foo(obj, y = obj.x):
    pass
```

This won't work for the same reason that the following won't work:

```
def foo(x, y = x+2):
    pass
```

The key to your confusion, I think, is that there is nothing special about the name "self".  It is easy to think that "self" is a key word that refers to the object (like in ruby, for instance), but it's not.  In Python, object's methods automatically pass the object as the first parameter, and it just happens to be conventional to call this first parameter "self".

If you have a class, object, and method call like:

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self, x, y):
        pass
a = A()
a.foo(1, 2)
```

You can basically think of the method call as implicitly calling:

```
a.foo(a, 1, 2)
```

Which isn't the most careful way of putting it, but I think it makes the idea clear enough.